# Removing subcategories from permalinks

Tags: categories, permalinks, mod-rewrite, core-modifications

I run a small news site with tens of thousands of entries.  I'm currently importing all of these into wordpress by rebuilding our old CMS into wordpress.  So far, everything is coming over smoothly.

My problem comes down to this:  We run several different news sections.  Sports, News, Arts, Oped, &c.  The way our current permalink structure is set up, a post looks like this:

`http://newssite.com/sports/2010/04/05/post-title.`

However, the post is also tagged with a subcategory like "football" or "basketball".

When I get everything into wordpress, permalinks want to show up as:

`http://newssite.com/sports/football/2010/04/05/post-title.`

**Is there a way to remove subcategories from showing up in permalinks?**  I would rather not hack core files, but am willing to if it fixes our problems.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the subcategory url altogether or the subcategory from showing in the post url only?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite you .htaccess if you are familiar with this.

Add the below line and try it:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```